# Android NetHunter can't find several files

Tags: root-access, linux, operating-system, oneplus-5

I'm trying to get KaliNethunter to work on my OnePlus5.

I'm facing a problem though, and I really don't know what to say of it. There are several errors and they're all `No such file or directory`.

This is the error log I get:

```
OnePlus5:/ # su -c bootkali
Mounting kali chroot...
mount: mounting /sdcard/kali-chroot.img on /data/local/nhsystem/kali-armhf failed: No such file or directory
/system/bin/bootkali: /data/data/com.offsec.nethunter/files/scripts/bootkali_init[268]: can't create /data/local/nhsystem/kali-armhf/etc/resolv.conf: No such file or directory
/system/bin/bootkali: /data/data/com.offsec.nethunter/files/scripts/bootkali_init[268]: can't create /data/local/nhsystem/kali-armhf/etc/resolv.conf: No such file or directory
/system/bin/bootkali: /data/data/com.offsec.nethunter/files/scripts/bootkali_init[268]: can't create /data/local/nhsystem/kali-armhf/etc/resolv.conf: No such file or directory
/system/bin/bootkali: /data/data/com.offsec.nethunter/files/scripts/bootkali_init[268]: can't create /data/local/nhsystem/kali-armhf/etc/resolv.conf: No such file or directory
/system/bin/bootkali: /data/data/com.offsec.nethunter/files/scripts/bootkali_init[268]: can't create /data/local/nhsystem/kali-armhf/etc/resolv.conf: No such file or directory
chmod: /data/local/nhsystem/kali-armhf/etc/resolv.conf: No such file or directory
chroot: can't execute '/bin/bash': No such file or directory
```

For the most part it seems I figured it out, but am still asking for assistance.

There is directory at `/data/local/nhsystem/kali-armhf/` however `/data/local/nhsystem/kali-armhf/etc/` isn't there. It exists in `/data/local/nhsystem/kali-armhf/system/etc/`.

So now I can either edit the `bootkali` script or mount the directory (I don't know how).

Kali Nethunter isn't necessarily supported with my device but is supported by older devices e.g. OnePlus3(T).

Comment: You can try creating directory yourself before executing script: `mkdir -p /data/local/nhsystem/kali-armhf`.